# How to access Screenshot images in Python, Pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using pyautogui to screenshot my current screen and I want to know if access to that image is possible via clipboard for further processing?
Code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
x = 1
while x < 4:
    capture = pyautogui.screenshot('/Users/Desktop/Screen/image'+str(x)+'.png')
    x += 1
    time.sleep(2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the pasting is possible. In general, to utilize the image, it may be converted to a cv2 image array for [further processing](https://youtu.be/jLzLNRK72KI) using OpenCv:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
x = 1
while x < 4:

    capture = pyautogui.screenshot('saved_'+str(x)+'.png')
    capture = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(capture), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("image",capture)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    x += 1
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry to ask but what is the difference between the two? I'm not trying to criticize your code or anything I just want to know for future reference, Thanks!

Comment: The pyautogui.screenshot() returns a PIL image object. We can either provide the destination path inside (as you did there), or using that image object with .save method. Both are fine. Since you asked about possibility of pasting that image, so yes you can use that capture object and even can convert it to opencv image for further processing. I have edited the answer with addition of cv2. Hopefully that solves your question.